# Dependency Injection - Resolve type without implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, repository

I'm trying to create a generic factory for my repositories in an ASP.NET project. Repositories take extra parameters in constructor, so they cannot be instantiated via dependency injection. In my factory, I would like to create repositories like this:

```
public TRepository Create <TRepository> (IUnitOfWork uow = null)
    where TRepository : IRepository
{
    return (TRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(TRepository), uow, _connectionFactory);
}
```

The problem is, that `TRepository` is the type of the interface, not implementation. On the other hand, I cannot add implementation for the type via DI because I want the factory to create the instance. **Is there some way to register the type of an implementation without registering an instance?**

Edit:
For clarification, this is how I'm using repositories.

```
using(var uow = _uowFactory.Create())
{
  var itemRepository = _repositoryFactory.Create<IItemRepository>(uow);         
  itemRepository.UpdateItem(request.Item);
  uow.Commit();
}
```

Comment: The AddSingleton has a `Func<>` overload  [AddSingleton(IServiceCollection, Type, Func<IServiceProvider,Object>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider_System_Object__). Is this what you mean?

Comment: "because I want the factory to create the instance". can you elaborate on why you want the repositories to be created by the factory?

Comment: @Steven Repositories in my application are not singletons. Instead, one instance of a repository is created for each context/transaction/UoW. I want to supply UoW as a parameter to create method. My goal is to implement UoW in such a way, that it does not "own" repositories.

Comment: Does the UoW come from the Container, or is it possible for you to pull the UoW from the Container? Same question for the connection factory. What is preventing you from letting the container resolve them, because in that case the container can resolve the repositories as well, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Steven Connection factory comes from container, but UoW is created by a factory as well. Basically there's one instance of UoW per db transaction.

Comment: And a db transaction, does that have the same lifetime as a scope from the container, or could it have same lifetime as a container scope?

Comment: @Steven I'm not sure if I understood the question. I added an example to the original question, if that clarifies it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving all registrations (back) into the Container. This allows the container to resolve complete object graphs and manage the Unit of Work. For instance:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionFactory>(_connectionFactory);
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork>(c => _uowFactory.Create());
services.AddScoped<IItemRepository, ItemRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();


using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    // Service depending on IItemRepository
    var controller =
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ItemController>();

    controller.Update(request.Item);

    var uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();

    uow.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using reflection and a cache in the repository factory.

Comment: How does the first line work? I assume it has to resolve an implementation somehow, how does it resolve it when you don't tell it what that implementation is?

Comment: @MRichards: The first line expects an existing, already created instance, which is what the OP has. It means the instance is *not* instantiated by the DI Container, but merely returned upon request.